# getstream i get chat is not enabled for the organization XXXXXXXX with id XXX

Tags: getstream-io

getstream  i get chat is not enabled for the organization XXXXXXXX with id XXX when trying to setuser on my applicaation

```
this.client=new StreamChat(myappisd)
    //   console.log(this.token)
      await this.client.setUser({id:this.$auth.user.id,name:this.$auth.user.first_name},this.token);
```

Comment: Hi there, if you're already on a paid plan please contact support. If not, did you start a chat trial for your organization?

Comment: how do i start a chat trial? i already registered

Comment: i started getting this error {"code":5,"message":"JWTAuth error: illegal base64 data at input byte 1","StatusCode":401,"duration":""}

Comment: finlly solved it, this is my new error  StreamChat error code 17: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "User 'tgcom' with role user is not allowed to access Resource ReadChannel on channel type messaging".

Comment: can you update the question to match the current problem (easier than comments)

Comment: If one of you could answer that one question of how to start a chat trial that would be so great. I've found this text 3-4 times across the internet with no answer. @Iamdevmaniac